# How to use apply and lambda to set value to a dataframe column based on the index matching another column in a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two dataframe

```
df1:

     item_id   height  weight 
13   19902     1.56    54
28   20503     1.7     30 

df2:
         height_2  weight_2 size-> (not supposed to be modified) 
item_id
19902     1        50     8
20503     2        30    10

expected output:
df2:
         height_2  weight_2 size-> (not supposed to be modified) 
item_id
19902     1.56        54      8
20503     1.7         30     10
```

I would like to replace the height and weight in d2 with the value found in d1. 
The usual way is to loop d2 and for each row, get the index and use the index to match against d1 to get the corresponding height and weight to write into d2. This is quite slow. 
Anyone know how to use a faster technique in panda dataframe, maybe the apply function ? I tried the following approach but it doesn't work:

```
df2['height'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df1.loc[(df1.item_id == x.name),['height']])
```

raise the following error:

```
> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with convert `item_id` to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), also for correctly match columnsnames is used `rename` by dictionary:

```
d = {'height':'height_2','weight':'weight_2'}
df2.update(df1.set_index('item_id').rename(columns=d))
print (df2)
         height_2  weight_2  size
item_id                          
19902        1.56        54     8
20503        1.70        30    10
```

Comment: I forgotten to mention df2 have more fields.  df1 is a reference table.
I try your code and it doesn't do any update when i print (df2)

i try df2 = df2.update(df1.set_index('item_id')) and it produce the following error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Df1 is a separate dataframe
Df2 is another dataframe with more columns than Df1 and their column name is different.
I am trying to replace height_2 and weight_2 of Df2 with values from height and weight ciolumn of Df1. The matching reference is the item_id

Comment: Thanks jezrael, i rewritten my question to make it clearer. Even if i do an update, it doesn't work. Probably the field name is different ?

Comment: Any alternative if column names are not the same ?